# With an LSI SAS 12G controller in JBOD personality, what exactly is behavior mode (JBOD vs. None)?

Tags: lsi, jbod

I am currently trying to configure an LSI SAS 12G HBA with the 3108 chip (it is a 9361-8i, but I am nearly sure that my question relates to similar HBAs as well).

I have understood the differences between the JBOD and the RAID ***personalities***, but there is another related setting which I currently can't make sense of. This setting is called ***behavior mode*** and is only available when the controller is in JBOD *personality*.

In JBOD *personality*, the *behavior mode* can be set to `JBOD` or `None`. Could somebody please shortly explain what this is about?

I have studied the manual linked below, and several more from Broadcom's web site, and have tried hard to find an explanation elsewhere as well, but to no avail.

The manual is here: https://docs.broadcom.com/doc/pub-005110

What I am talking about is shown e.g.

- In chapter 5.3.3 on page 111

> "JBOD- The Behavior modes available under this mode are JBOD and
> None."

- In the last row of table 29 on page 135
- In the third-to-last row of table 42 on page 196

... and eventually a few more.